# Serial data issue

Tags: python, serialization, arduino, pyserial

I want to make a program that receives data from the serial port so it can be looked for as an entry of a dictionary on Python 2.7.5 and Arduino 1.8. :

```
import serial #Import Serial Library
arduinoSerialData =serial.Serial('com3',9600)
y={"a":"hello","b":"How are you?"}
while (1==1):
    if(arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
        myData=str(arduinoSerialData.readline())
        print y.get(myData,"error")
```

I don't know what is happening, but the program always prints "error"
However, if I try only printing the variable "myData" it does print exactly what Arduino is sending.
Please, help.

Comment: Does `myData` have a trailing newline in the string that you don't notice when printing it out?

Comment: In the Arduino program, I send it with a Serial.println('a');
Is that a problem?

Comment: Well yes, the `get` will be comparing `'a\n'` against `'a'` and not matching hence your error. `myData.strip()` will remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. :D